# Trying to add slideToggle() function but it ain't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom styled select options code for selecting years and months. I want to add jquery slideToggle() effect to it. I'm trying with selecting custom defined classes but it ain't working. Following is my code:

```js
/*
Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/BB3JK/47/
*/

$('select').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;
  
    $this.addClass('select-hidden'); 
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
    $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());
  
    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'select-options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);
  
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }
  
    var $listItems = $list.children('li');
  
    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
    });
  
    $listItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        //console.log($this.val());
    });
  
    $(document).click(function() {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

});

//select dropdown slide function
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".select-styled").click(function(){
    $(".select-options").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato");
body {
  font-family: Lato, Arial;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 span {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
p a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: #b83729;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
p a:hover {
  background-color: #ab3326;
}

.select-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 220px;
  height: 40px;
}

.select-styled {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #c0392b;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.select-styled:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10px;
}
.select-styled:hover {
  background-color: #b83729;
}
.select-styled:active, .select-styled.active {
  background-color: #ab3326;
}
.select-styled:active:after, .select-styled.active:after {
  top: 9px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}

.select-options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ab3326;
}
.select-options li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-indent: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #962d22;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}
.select-options li:hover {
  color: #c0392b;
  background: #fff;
}
.select-options li[rel="hide"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<select id="mounth">
    <option value="hide">-- Month --</option>
    <option value="january" rel="icon-temperature">January</option>
    <option value="february">February</option>
    <option value="march">March</option>
    <option value="april">April</option>
    <option value="may">May</option>
    <option value="june">June</option>
    <option value="july">July</option>
    <option value="august">August</option>
    <option value="september">September</option>
    <option value="october">October</option>
    <option value="november">November</option>
    <option value="december">December</option>
</select> 

<select id="year">
    <option value="hide">-- Year --</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After adding the slideToggle() script, it's somehow sliding both the select menus at the same time and that too in very ugly manner (as you can experience in attached snippet). Please help me make the slideToggle() effect perfect.

Comment: "ain't workin" is not a clear problem statement.  Please read [mcve], particularly the _clear problem statement_ portion.

Answer (score 1):

`$(".select-options").slideToggle("slow");` will select both the dropdowns. Instead get the next element of clicked element and apply `slideToggle` to it.

```
$(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
```

```js
$('select').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

  $this.addClass('select-hidden');
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
  $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

  var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
  $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

  var $list = $('<ul />', {
    'class': 'select-options'
  }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    $('<li />', {
      text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($list);
  }

  var $listItems = $list.children('li');

  $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
    });
    // $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
  });

  $listItems.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
    //console.log($this.val());
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
  });

});

//select dropdown slide function
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select-styled").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato");
body {
  font-family: Lato, Arial;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 span {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

p a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: #b83729;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

p a:hover {
  background-color: #ab3326;
}

.select-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 220px;
  height: 40px;
}

.select-styled {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #c0392b;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.select-styled:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10px;
}

.select-styled:hover {
  background-color: #b83729;
}

.select-styled:active,
.select-styled.active {
  background-color: #ab3326;
}

.select-styled:active:after,
.select-styled.active:after {
  top: 9px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}

.select-options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ab3326;
}

.select-options li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-indent: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #962d22;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}

.select-options li:hover {
  color: #c0392b;
  background: #fff;
}

.select-options li[rel="hide"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <select id="mounth">
    <option value="hide">-- Month --</option>
    <option value="january" rel="icon-temperature">January</option>
    <option value="february">February</option>
    <option value="march">March</option>
    <option value="april">April</option>
    <option value="may">May</option>
    <option value="june">June</option>
    <option value="july">July</option>
    <option value="august">August</option>
    <option value="september">September</option>
    <option value="october">October</option>
    <option value="november">November</option>
    <option value="december">December</option>
  </select>

  <select id="year">
    <option value="hide">-- Year --</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Just wanted to know that why the menus aren't sliding when we click outside the select bars? And slide down effect is ok but option menus are sliding up a bit slower when we click back on Month/Year bar. Plus the behavior of arrows now not working as desired as they are now always downward after rotation. Please help in this regard now!

Answer (score 0):

I forked the original jsfiddle you had as a comment in your html. I added slideToggle("slow") on the show elements and slideUp("slow") on the hide elements. This seems to handle your issues from randomSouls solution. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ywv32ud8/ and I have added the working solution below. If you really want the slideToggle on both I can make a different solution but this seemed easier than making a whole new function rather than use what was already there. Hope this helps.

```js
// Iterate over each select element
$('select').each(function () {

    // Cache the number of options
    var $this = $(this),
        numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    // Hides the select element
    $this.addClass('s-hidden');

    // Wrap the select element in a div
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

    // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
    $this.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

    // Cache the styled div
    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.styledSelect');

    // Show the first select option in the styled div
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    // Cache the list items
    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)
    $styledSelect.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.styledSelect.active').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').slideToggle("slow");
    });

    // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
    // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
    $listItems.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.slideUp("slow");
        /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
    });

    // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
    $(document).click(function () {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.slideUp("slow");
    });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Lato, Arial;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 span {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

p a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: #b83729;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

p a:hover {
  background-color: #ab3326;
}

.s-hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.select {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 220px;
  height: 40px;
}
.styledSelect {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #c0392b;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.styledSelect:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10px;
}
.styledSelect:hover {
  background-color: #b83729;
}
.styledSelect:active, .styledSelect.active {
   background-color: #ab3326;
}
.styledSelect:active:after,
.styledSelect.active:after{
  top: 9px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}
.options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ab3326;
}
.options li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-indent: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #962d22;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}
.options li:hover {
  color: #c0392b;
  background: #fff;
}

.options li[rel="hide"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <select id="mounth">
    <option value="hide">-- Month --</option>
    <option value="january" rel="icon-temperature">January</option>
    <option value="february">February</option>
    <option value="march">March</option>
    <option value="april">April</option>
    <option value="may">May</option>
    <option value="june">June</option>
    <option value="july">July</option>
    <option value="august">August</option>
    <option value="september">September</option>
    <option value="october">October</option>
    <option value="november">November</option>
    <option value="december">December</option>
  </select>

  <select id="year">
    <option value="hide">-- Year --</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but the menus aren't closing when we click the selected option back.